# Adding new lines to .htaccess breaks the whole site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have an issue that when I add a simple line to the .htaccess file it immediately gives me an internal server error. I have no idead what is wrong, the current content of the .htaccess file is the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If I add a line and get the .htaccess file looking like below, it immediately breaks the site and gives me 500 Internal server error:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Begin security
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Could you kindly let me know what I can check in order to stop this from happening?

Another thing which I also noticed is that if I add a security plugin through wordpress, and start enabling things, it also breaks the site.

I have also looked in the error log when trying to load the site and the following is the error I get:

```
.htaccess: order not allowed here
```

Comment: Look at the error log, it contains a detailed message what's wrong.

Comment: The documentation specifies `<Files "filename"> ... </Files>` as syntax. Note the quote chars.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider the error I get when I load the site is the following: `.htaccess: order not allowed here`

Comment: @arkascha I have tried that and still breaks the site. It is not about which command it is just breaking the whole site.

Comment: If the syntax is invalid, then obviously "the whole site" is broken, since all `.htaccess` style files are evaluated for each request. An error blocks that, the requests cannot be served. That is one of the many issues when using such files. Question is why your http server refuses to accept the `opder` command here...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, what I noticed is that the following configuration in my directory was blocking the .htaccess to work

```
AllowOverride FileInfo Options
```

Changed it to the following and everything

```
AllowOverride All
```